# Extjs6: gridpanel - multilevel grouping

Tags: extjs, grid, multi-level, group

On a project written with ExtJs 6, I'm looking for the ability to have multi-level grouping on a grid.
I don't want to group the records on multiple columns but on one level, but each column to be grouped on its own level.

I found some examples for ExtJs, but all pages have broken link to source code (old references).

My goal is to be able to group columns on one, two or three levels depending on the user's choice.
Gridpanel ExtJs proposes by default to group only on one level. I'm looking to expand that.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use a Tree Grid, each branch being a level.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by migrate ExtJs framework to version 7.5
And then using the "AdvancedGroupingSummary" grid's feature which allows multi-level grouping